# Why can't I generate a solution for the C++ project (.cryproject)?

Tags: c++, game-development, generate, cryengine

I am a beginner and follow the lessons from the c++ CryEngine documentation. But the problem is that I can't go any further until I generate a solution for the c++ project

I don't even have an icon for the corresponding buttons in the menu
I can provide a couple of screenshots

I tried different versions of the engine to solve the problem with generating the solution for the project, but all in vain

https://ibb.co/nL3SYKp

Answer (score 0):

Open up Visual Studio Installer and make sure you have the latest Windows SDK installed, besides the one required by Cryengine.

[For me it was Windows 11 SDK (10.0.22621.0).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMc7e.png)